# Removing vowels by replacing it with index in the String

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace the vowels of a given string with the index of the same. I'm trying to use .replace() and .index() but it doesn't work.
I have something like this:

```
def vowels(w):
vowel = 'aeiou'
for i in w:
    if i in vowel:
        a = w.replace(i, w.index(str(w.find('aeiou'))))
    return a
```

The idea is this:

input = 'Hi Everyone'

output = 'H1 3v5ry8n10'

Answer (score 2):

In this situation using `.replace()` isn't a good idea. Generally `.replace()` will do an operation on all vowels in the string, but in this situation you want to replace each vowel with a very specific value. A generator comprehension with `join` is better here:

```
vowels = set('aeiou')
s = "Hi Everyone"

replaced = ''.join(str(i) if c.lower() in vowels else c for i, c in enumerate(s))
print(replaced)
```

Output:

```
H1 3v5ry8n10
```

Comment: Swapping `i` and `c` would help readability. [i]ndex  and [c]haracter

Comment: @VikrantSharma, edited. I've always thought of them as item and count.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` takes a 3rd argument telling it how many characters to replace. For your purposes you need to replace one each time.

`index` will give you the position of a character and `str` will make it a string.

Using `lower` makes sure all cases are matched.

Replace used characters in `w` to include duplicates. Make sure it a list and the replacement is not a single character so it works for all strings.

```
def vowels(w):
    vowel = 'aeiou'
    a = w
    w = list(w)
    for i in w:
        if i.lower() in vowel:
            a = a.replace(i, str(w.index(i)), 1)
            w[w.index(i)] = 0
    return a
```

In: `Hi Everyone`
Out: `H1 3v5ry8n10`

Comment: You may want to use an accumulator separate from the original `w` so that longer strings retain the index from the original string. Otherwise, later vowels will get bigger indices as those before them get replaced with two or more digits (e.g. `vowels('Hi EveryoneA')` yields `'H1 3v5ry8n1012'`, when it is probably expected to yield `'H1 3v5ry8n1011'`).

Comment: @CraigMeier You're right. I edited my answer so that the code works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind @Craig Meier's comment, the easiest way to keep track of the position of an element while iterating, is using `enumerate`. This makes the `find` operation unnecessary, and the code simpler.

The most Pythonic way to do this is of course what @Primusa proposes, but I think there's value in showing a more step-by-step approach.

```
def vowels(w):
    vowel = 'aeiou'
    for pos, char in enumerate(w):  # extract a character and remember its position
        if char.lower() in vowel:   # check if it belongs to the check set
            w = w.replace(char, str(pos), 1)  # replace just the first instance
    return w

inp = 'Hi Everyone'
output = vowels(inp)
print(output)
```